# How to have a window pop up when progress bar finishes in c#

Tags: c#

I have seen a similar answer but it's not in c# so I decided to ask this question.
https://gyazo.com/3ff6efd90fa390cd1f071b693027fcd3 After it reaches that point I want a window to pop up which says "Successfully loaded...". The timer interval I have set is 50 if that helps.
This is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Start();
    }

private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
```

Comment: If you've implemented your progress bar using a backgroundworker then use the runworkercompleted event and use a messagebox to display your message

Comment: So, your ProgressBar is not measuring anything at all, but the passage of time?

Comment: I'm new to c#, that's what I've been trying to figure out. That's what I initially tried, when the interval reaches X it runs the MessageBox.Show command but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
```

to:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var before = this.progressBar1.Value;
    this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
    var after = this.progressBar1.Value;
    if (after > before && after == this.progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully loaded...");
    }
}
```

By checking whether the value changed **and** that the current value is `Maximum`, you know that the progress bar has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check in your code if `Value` has reached `Maximum` after a step is performed:

```
progressBar.PerformStep();

if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum)
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully loaded...");
```

Using a BackgroundWorker instance:

```
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroudWorker();
bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
bgw.ProgressChanged += bgw_ProgressChanged;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

private void bgw_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 total = 147;

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < total; ++i)
    {
        Int32 progress = (i * 100) / total;
        bgw.ReportProgress(progress, i);
    }
}

private void bgw_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully loaded...");
}
```

**EDIT**

Since the question changed providing a code snipped, here is an updated answer (that, by the way, reflects my first proposal):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Increment(1);

    if (this.progressBar1.Value == this.progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        //...

        MessageBox.Show("Successfully loaded...");
    }
}
```